# Heroku Rails could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-postgresql

I have 3 Rails applications that all use the same code base. 2/3 of the applications are running fine, but one of them gives me this error:

> could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory

Upon trying to look at the Postgres logs, it is a little more specific:

> psql: bin//psql-9.2.1-64bit pv: bin//pv-1.1.4-64bit psql-9.2.1-64bit:
>   could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
>   could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
>   could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
>   bin/brie: line 146: [: : integer expression expected pg_dump:
>   bin//pg_dump-9.2.1-64bit psql-9.2.1-64bit:
> could not fork new process
>   for connection: Cannot allocate memory
> could not fork new process for
>   connection: Cannot allocate memory
> could not fork new process for
>   connection: Cannot allocate memory

This is a relatively small app, especially data-wise. I have tried re-pushing everything, I have tried heroku-restart, and Heroku's status page says they're fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hours later, the problem seems to have "resolved itself." I am going to leave this question unanswered because, well, I still don't have an answer. What if this happens again?

Comment: Are you on a free dyno? Are you on a free database?

Comment: This was an isolated incident with that database server. Should be fixed now. If you continue to see it, migrate to a new host with pgbackups: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups

Comment: Heroku guys fixed it. I was on free database though.

Comment: I had the same problem an hour ago. Now, everything works fine. Still don't understand why should I migrate to a new host with pgbackups. I am on a free dyno.

Comment: Having the same issue now. The database server has been down for over 13 hours, and there is no response from Heroku to the ticket I submitted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heroku people fixed it. Their problem

Comment: Just had a similar problem, was caused by a noisy neighbor using too much memory.

Comment: It happened to us today.  Unfortunately given the limited control over DB given by Heroku there was nothing we could do. Is there a way to restart DB?

Comment: I haven't done this myself, and it may not address this core problem much, but it looks like you can kill Postgres processes via `heroku pg:ps` to see the processes then `heroku pg:kill 2048 -a example_app_name` to kill the process. https://help.heroku.com/I6HY032G/how-do-i-fix-a-stuck-postgres-process