# Django OperationalError: could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

Our site on Heroku is suddenly down and the following errors are seen in the logs.
Any idea how to start troubleshooting this issue? Have tried contacting support and waiting for a reply. Is there a way to restart the Postgres database?

```
2015-12-17T02:45:34.631406+00:00 app[web.2]: OperationalError: could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
2015-12-17T02:45:34.631406+00:00 app[web.2]:
2015-12-17T02:45:34.631407+00:00 app[web.2]: could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory
2015-12-17T02:45:34.631407+00:00 app[web.2]: could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory 2015-12-17T02:45:34.631408+00:00 app[web.2]:  2015-12-17T02:45:34Z app[postgres.8]: 
[DATABASE] could not fork autovacuum worker process: Cannot allocate memory 2015-12-17T02:45:35Z app[postgres.8]:
[DATABASE] could not fork autovacuum worker process: Cannot allocate memory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku Rails could not fork new process for connection: Cannot allocate memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149021/heroku-rails-could-not-fork-new-process-for-connection-cannot-allocate-memory)